# Obter informações sobre uma tabela de dados através do SAP

Tags: tabela-banco-de-dados, exportação, erp, abap

No SAP temos a transação SE11 onde é possível visualizar e alterar características de uma tabela de dados, seria possível exportar para um arquivo txt ou csv as seguintes informações:

1. Nome da coluna
2. Elemento de dados

Alguém já gerou um arquivo txt demonstrando as colunas e seus elementos de dados de uma tabela específica?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função DDIF_FIELDINFO_GET para pegar todos os dados de uma tabela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: print da função]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]